# How does Lelouch manage to contain his Geass?

Tags: code-geass

I've recently just finished Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion, now I've started R2. As much as I've started to love this, I noticed one little thing that I can't quite put my finger on. (I haven't heard anything in the anime about it either.)

I was led to believe that he was still unable to control his Geass (assumption based on how the first season ended), yet when he's around Milly, Shirley etc., it appears he has it under control?

Am I missing something?

Comment: There's an explanation for this early on in R2. I believe it's in episode 3. Have you watched episode 3 yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lelouch obtains eye contacts for his geass eye from CC in episode 3 of R2. It depends on the video, but it happens around the 12-13 minute mark in a flashback.

Comment: Yes, I realized last night as I continued on from episode 2. Thank you! I should be more patient